# Django - user permissions to certain views?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-permissions, django-login

From the admin I see that you can allocate permissions to a user or a user group  to :allow add, change or delete data from a model.

That is great, but I also need to allow a user or a user group to access or not a group of views. I have certain type of services on my web site so I want to allow some users to access a certain services (pages/views) but not others.

So how can I allow certain users/user groups access to certain views? Thank you!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Users that cannot add or change etc. a certain model, will not be able to see it in the admin.

If we are talking about your custom created views then you could create something which checks a user for a permission and returns a 404 if they do not have that permission. Permissions are linked to models and a group can be assigned various permissions.

You can add a permission to a model like this:

```
# myproject/myapp/models.py

class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('permission_code', 'Friendly permission description'),
        )
```

Then you can check a if a user has permission like this:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('myapp.permission_code'))
def some_view(request):
    # ...
```

Using permissions you can then easily add or remove them from users and groups simply using the admin interface.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the custom views I've created not the admin.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try. Looks relatively easy.

Comment: @permission_required would be easier and more elegant here

Comment: @Manur Sounds better yes. I answered this in Jan 2011: But I can't remember if the `permission_required` decorator was around then.

Comment: Make sure to migrate or syncdb to use them. I racked my brain trying to figure that out until I found this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions

Answer (score 10):

You need to manage that manually, but it's pretty easy. Presumably there's an attribute that determines whether or not a group has permission to see a view: then you just decorate that view with either the `permission_required` decorator, if it's a simple question of whether the user has a particular Permission, or `user_passes_test` if it's a bit more complicated:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_allowed_to_see_view_myview())
def myview(request):
    ...etc...
```

assuming that `is_allowed_to_see_view_myview` is some sort of method on the User object.

The [authentication docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test) are pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 4):

For class based views you can inherit  `UserPassesTestMixin` class into the view and define `test_func`

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class MainView(UserPassesTestMixin, View):

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.has_perm('app.get_main_view')
```

Take a look at [this docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) for more details on how to use this:

Comment: Important information, it's quite recent django's feature (versions 1.9+)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Django 1.9+, you should be able to use [`PermissionRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin):

For example:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin

class MainView(PermissionRequiredMixin, View):
    permission_required = 'my_services.foo_bar'
    ...
```

This is basically a special case of `UserPassesTestMixin`, designed specifically to test whether the user has the indicated permission.

Answer (score 1):

Permissions system is model-centric and assumes that permissions are tied to models.  I think following 2 alternatives are best options:

A. If your views are related to some specific model, use custom permissions on that model as Marcus Whybrow suggested.

B. [not tested, might not work] Subclasss `User` and define your own permissions there.  You don't need actual model, it's just wrapper for your app's custom permission:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class MyUser(User):
    class Meta:
        permissions = (('can_visit_$viewset1', 'Can visit $view_set_1'))
```

Don't forget to run `syncdb` to add custom permissions to database.

Comment: As of Django 1.3 there is no way to subclass User (apart from using AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE, but that doesn't help here).