# redirect certain user to certain view in django

Tags: python, django

i need to know how to redirect the user in Django views to a certain page after he logs in. 
let's say we have 3 types of users and 3 types of pages, i want each type to be directed to a certain page, and in the same time doesn't has the permission to view the other pages.

Comment: What do you have so far? Post some code you've tried and isn't working. Basically you need to identify the user type (include the type in the user model?) and then redirect according to that. But there's more to it than this. You'll see once you try.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
@login_required
def home(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(
               reverse(custom_view, 
                       args=[request.user.username]))
```

Here, custom_view should be your user specific view. This is assuming you have:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profiles/home'
```

and you have configured a urlpattern:

```
(r'^profiles/home', 'myapp.views.home')
```

You can add a check for account type and redirect to the correct view.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but what if i increased the number of users and change it to a group per page ? is there anyway to check if a user or more has premission to view a page !

Comment: Yes, you can add/remove permissions based on groups or users. You might want to check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597401/django-user-permissions-to-certain-views) here.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some similar functionality recently by sub-classing the LoginView provided by django.contrib.auth.  Okay, make your first page from the root directory, call it login: 
`python manage.py startapp login`.  Make this file exist `<projectRoot>/login/templates/registration/login.html`  Add this code inside said file, it's more or less cut and pasted from bootstrap's login form, but with some standard django template language to bind to the expected AuthenticationForm fields.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    <title>Signin to yourWebsite.com</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="text-center">
    <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}?next=clockin">
    {% csrf_token %}
      <img class="mb-4" src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
      <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
      <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
      <!--input id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="True" autofocus="" type="email"-->
      {{form.username}}
      <label for="id_password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
      {{form.password}}
      <!--input id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="True" type="password"-->
      <div class="checkbox mb-3">
        <label>
          <input value="remember-me" type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">© 2018</p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
<script>
    $("#id_password").attr({
        "class":"form-control",
        "placeholder":"Password",
        "required":"True",
        "type":"password",
    });
    $("#id_username").attr({"class":"form-control",
        "placeholder":"Email address",
        "required":"True",
        "type":"email",
    });
</script>
<style>
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.form-signin {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.form-signin .checkbox {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.form-signin .form-control {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.form-signin .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 2;
}
.form-signin input[type="email"] {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.form-signin input[type="password"] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
</style>
```

Next, subclass the built in view and override the redirect part.  Inside login.views.py, add this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class CustomLoginview(LoginView):

    def get_redirect_url(self):
        if self.request.user.groups.filter(name="customer").exists():
            return 'invoice'
        return super().get_redirect_url()
```

Finally, update urls.py:

```
from login.views import CustomLoginview

urlpatterns = [
    path('', CustomLoginview.as_view(), name='login'),
```

I'm telling the login page to go to my next app 'invoice' if the user is a customer, otherwise it goes to the default that I specified in the settings file.  Obviously you could expound upon the concept for 3 types of users, which is different than routing based on the names of users, not sure how that got 2 upvotes.